# Two Questions on Sharepoint Publishing Sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, publishing, publishing-site

1. I have a custom page layout which is based on a custom content type. I have placed several textfields and lookup fields from custom content type in the page layout. I want them to be seen to only admins. Contributers should not see and edit. Is this possible?
2. Admins will select an item in a lookup combobox in page layout. I want to fetch some data from other lists using the selected item for filtering. I guess I can place a data view in page layout but how I get certain field value of the page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a look at the [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol%28v=office.12%29.aspx) it will allow you to hide sections of the page based on the rights a user has.
2. Why don't you just use a lookup column?

Comment: SPSecurityTrimmedControl is the way I guess, thank you. About the second one, I don't want user to forced to choose every column himself. It should be enough for him to choose only the first distinctive one, and the rest should fill in automatically.

Comment: Ah i see.. sounds like a custom dev job.